# how to stretch selected menu item to the left edge of the window?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a block with several items. When I click on the menu item it is highlighting and extending to the left border of the window.

I did this with the help of an absolutely positioned element, and set the width to 1000px, but this option does not work. This red bar should rest against the edge of the window at any resolution.

[image]

[image]

html

```
<div class="flex-menu-area">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="flex-menu">
                <div class="left-flex-column">
                    <div class="flex-menu-select"><span>item 1</span></div>
                    <div class="flex-menu-select"><span>item 2</span></div>
                    <div class="flex-menu-select"><span>item 3</span></div>
                </div>
                <div class="right-left-column">
                    <div class="object"><span>item1content</span></div>
                    <div class="object"><span>item1content</span></div>
                    <div class="object"><span>item1content</span></div>
                    <div class="object"><span>item1content</span></div>
                    <div class="object"><span>item1content</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

css

```
.flex-menu-area {
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 512px;
    .flex-menu {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        height: 100%;
        .left-flex-column {
            max-width: 256px;
            width: 100%;
            outline: 1px solid gray;
            height: 512px;
            .flex-menu-select {
                font-size: 20px;
                line-height: 26px;
                font-weight: 600;
                text-align: left;
                color: $text-color;
                padding-top: 43px;
                padding-bottom: 43px;
                max-width: 100%;
                border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
                position: relative;
                &:hover {
                    background: #ccc;
                    &:before {
                        position: absolute;
                        width: 1000px;
                        height: 100%;
                        content: "";
                        display: block;
                        top: 0px;
                        left: -1000px;
                        background: red;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        .right-left-column {
            outline: 1px solid gray;
            height: 512px;
            width: 884px;
            background: #fff;
            display: -webkit-flex;
            display: -moz-flex;
            display: -ms-flex;
            display: -o-flex;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-between;
            background: #eee;
            .object {
                outline: 1px solid red;
                font-size: 20px;
                line-height: 40px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Solution:

```
&:before {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    top: 0px;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: instead of `1000px` set it to `100%` ?

Comment: This will not work correctly. 100% will be from the width of flex-menu-select.

Comment: can you build a JS fiddle by any chance ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the width and left values of your &:before to:

```
width: calc((100vw - 100%) /2);
left: calc(0 - ((100vw - 100%) /2));
```

I think that should help, but I don't have access to a screen large enough to test right now so apologies if my calcs are slightly off.

Comment: Working solution:

&:before {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100vw;
 right: 0;
 height: 100%;
 content: "";
 display: block;
 top: 0px;
 background: #fff;
 z-index: -1;
}